# How can I edit a contact that I have previously created with an contact form?

Tags: javascript

I am creating an AddressBook, and I want to be able to edit a contact once I have created it.

This is my code for displaying the contacts :

```
 var AddressBook = [{Scott, Smith, Sepulveda 112, 678587587}];     

 var displayContacts = function (data) {

  var contactListNode = document.getElementById('contactList');
  while (contactListNode.firstChild) {
    contactListNode.removeChild(contactListNode.firstChild);
  };

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var contactInfo = document.createTextNode(
      "Name: " + data[i].firstname + " " +
      data[i].lastname + " Address: " +
      data[i].address + " Phone: " +
      data[i].phone
    )

    li.appendChild(contactInfo);
    li.setAttribute('id', i);
    li.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleteContact()');
    document.getElementById('contactList').appendChild(li);
  }
};

var storeFormInfos = function () {

  var contact = {
    firstname: document.getElementById('firstname').value,
    lastname: document.getElementById('lastname').value,
    address: document.getElementById('address').value,
    phone: document.getElementById('phone').value
  };

  addressBook.push(contact);
  displayContacts(addressBook);

  document.getElementById('firstname').value = "",
    document.getElementById('lastname').value = "",
    document.getElementById('address').value = "",
    document.getElementById('phone').value = ""
};
```

AND I treat var AddressBook as the data to displayContacts().

```
<div id="addContactForm">
  <div>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="firstname">
  </div>
  <div>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="lastname">
  </div>
  <div>
    Address:<br>
    <input type="text" id="address">
  </div>
  <div>
    Phone:<br>
    <input type="text" id="phone">
  </div>
  <br><br>
</div>
<button onclick="storeFormInfos()">Submit</button>

<ul id="contactList">

</ul>
```

Here there is the HTML form for creating a contact and the ul where it is going to be stored.

Thanks.

Comment: `data` appears to be an Array that is being passed to `displayContacts`, so that's where the data is and that's what needs to be altered to make changes to the data. You should show the additional code where `data` is set up and populated as well as the applicable HTML.

Comment: What exactly are you asking to do? You show code for displaying contacts, but you ask for code to edit them. What have you tried so far? Also can you supply some sample data?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I have added the function I use to to edit the contacts and the data.

Comment: But you still haven't added the code that sets up/populates the actual array `addressBook` AND please add the relevant HTML as well.

Comment: @ScottMarcus the thing I want to do for example is being able to modify the last name of the contact stored the AddressBook from Smith to Marcus.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have some syntax errors:

- `[{Scott, Smith, Sepulveda 112, 678587587}]` is invalid syntax for an `Object`
- Your array is declared as `AddressBook`, while your reference to it
  is `addressBook`

I've modified your code to correct the syntax issues and updated it to follow modern standards and best practices.

For editing, there are several ways to go about it. You could place an edit button next to each address that would make it easy to know which object in the array needs to be updated. Here, I've simplified it a bit for demonstration so you can just see how the edit actually happens.

See the comments for explanations:

```js
// Get references to DOM elements you'll need just once
const frm = document.querySelector("form");
const contactListNode = document.getElementById('contactList');
const fName = document.getElementById('firstname');
const lName = document.getElementById('lastname');
const address = document.getElementById('address');
const phone = document.getElementById('phone');
const btnEdit = document.getElementById("btnEdit");
const btnSubmit = document.getElementById("btnSubmit");

// Set up event handlers in JavaScript, not in HTML
btnSubmit.addEventListener("click", storeFormInfos);
btnEdit.addEventListener("click", editContact);

var addressBook = [];    

function storeFormInfos() {

  // Create a new object that uses the values from the elements
  var contact = {
    "First name": fName.value,
    "Last name": lName.value,
    "Address": address.value,
    "Phone": phone.value
  };

  addressBook.push(contact);     // Put object into array
  displayContacts(addressBook);  // Update the UI to show list
  frm.reset();                   // Reset the form fields
}

function displayContacts(data) {
  contactListNode.innerHTML = ""; // Clear out previous list

  // Loop over the objects in the array
  addressBook.forEach(function(contact){
    var li = document.createElement('li');  // Create a bullet element
    var stringContent = "";                 // Will hold text for bullet
    
    // Loop over properties of object
    for(var prop in contact){
      // Write text based on property name and value
      stringContent += " " + prop + ": " + contact[prop];
    }
    li.textContent = stringContent;   // Set string as text of bullet
    contactListNode.appendChild(li);  // Add bullet to list
  });
}

function editContact(){
  var idx = prompt("Which contact (by number) do you wish to edit?");
  
  // Did user enter a valid index?
  if(addressBook[idx-1]){
    var newLastName = prompt("What is the new last name?");
    addressBook[idx-1]["Last name"] = newLastName;      // Update address book
  } else { alert("That's not a valid index!"); }
  displayContacts(addressBook);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div id="addContactForm">
    <div>First name:<br><input type="text" id="firstname"></div>
    <div>Last name:<br><input type="text" id="lastname"></div>
    <div>Address:<br><input type="text" id="address"></div>
    <div>Phone:<br><input type="text" id="phone"></div>
    <br><br>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button><button type="button" id="btnEdit">Edit</button>
<form>
<ul id="contactList"></ul>
```